# How would I import my id_rsa ssh key in test-kitchen (kitchen.yml) so I may use it to log into all kitchen managed VMs?

Tags: vagrant, test-kitchen

from my kitchen.yml I am using the vagrant driver and trying to get my id_rsa key to import so that I may use it to ssh into these hosts. Here is my kitchen.yml:

```
#kitchen.yml
---
driver:
name: vagrant

# Ansible configuration
provisioner:
  name: ansible_playbook
#  ansible_cfg_path: <%= ENV['WORKSPACE'] %>/ansible.cfg
  ansible_extra_flags: <%= ENV['ANSIBLE_EXTRA_FLAGS'] %>
  roles_path: <%= ENV['WORKSPACE'] %>/roles
  playbook: <%= ENV['WORKSPACE'] %>/kubernetes.yml
  ansible_inventory: <%= ENV['WORKSPACE'] %>/inventory.yml
  hosts: kubernetes
  require_pip: true
#  requirements_path:
  ansible_verbose: true
  ansible_verbosity: 2
  ansible_diff: true
  ansible_version: latest
  require_chef_for_busser: false
  ansible_connection: ssh
  ansible_host_key_checking: false
  private_key: $HOME/.ssh/swat.pem
  additional_ssh_private_keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

transport:
  ssh_key: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  connection_timeout: 10
  connection_retries: 5

# Vagrant network configuration
platforms:
  - name: centos7-01
    driver_plugin: vagrant
    driver_config:
      box: centos/7
      network:
        - ['public_network', {bridge: "en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)", ip: '192.168.0.11'}]
    ssh_key: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - name: centos7-02
    driver_plugin: vagrant
    driver_config:
      box: centos/7
      network:
        - ['public_network', {bridge: "en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)", ip: '192.168.0.12'}]
  - name: centos7-03
    driver_plugin: vagrant
    driver_config:
      box: centos/7
      network:
        - ['public_network', {bridge: "en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)", ip: '192.168.0.13'}]
  - name: centos7-04
    driver_plugin: vagrant
    driver_config:
      box: centos/7
      network:
        - ['public_network', {bridge: "en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)", ip: '192.168.0.14'}]

# Deployment/Environment settings
suites:
  - name: version-1-0
    run_list:
    attributes:
```

As you can see, I am trying greate many methods to get my key imported.

When I attempt to use my key after the VM builds, I just see the following error:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa vagrant@192.168.0.11
The authenticity of host '192.168.0.11 (192.168.0.11)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:OlCjFbGhdpm+NH9vs3AdBcCV+A7QWNSn3nG05evnBGI.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.0.11' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
vagrant@192.168.0.11: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

It still seems to only connect only if it uses the private_key generated by the `kitchen create` command.

Answer (score 0):

when you spin up a node instance using kitchen, the node comes baked with [`vagrant` user](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/base.html#quot-vagrant-quot-user)

> By default, Vagrant expects a "vagrant" user to SSH into the machine as.

this allows vagrant to be able to connect to the node via ssh.
when you specify a key for the ssh connection, you basically override the default key that vagrant offers when establishing ssh connection.

if you wish to use your own key, then you must make sure that your ssh configuration (username, key file, etc.) coincide with the operating system ssh server.

basically you can create your own custom vagrant box, but since you are using configuration management (ansible), i would stongly advise you to leave vagrant ssh configuration as it, while leveraging ansible to create a user and its ssh configuration.